# JBoss - Function called on onblur event not giving any results or alerts

Tags: jsp, jboss, weblogic, dom-events, onblur

I have few text boxes in my JSP. My requirement (for one of the text boxes) is to check the length of data entered by user in it, if it is less than the Max Length, I need to Prefix that many Zeros and Make it of Max Length.

I had some existing code with existing functionality.

I have just added some part in `onblur` event. As can be seen in the code below, I have tried to set the value from `zrs` variable when `onblur` occurs.

The `zrs` variable is in turn being set by calling a `zeros()` function.

I have pasted the code below for `zeros()` function for the reference.

It's worth noting that, when I am deploying my code on Weblogic server, it works fine. It even gives me correct results and also the alerts added as part of Zeros function.

But when I am deploying the same on JBoss, it does not give any alerts as well.
I am using Internet Explorer for both the applications, built on Web Logic and JBoss.

Can someone please look into it and guide me?

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${dto.loadpage == true}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="tmpValue[<c:out value="${indexDto}"/>]"  value="<c:out value="${dto.valeurSaisiForm}"/>"/>
                                            <c:set var="prop" value="calculer(this,${dto.valMaxChamp},'${nomDuChamp}',${indexDto});"/>
                                            <c:set var="zrs" value ="zeros(this,${dto.valMaxChamp},'${nomDuChamp}',${indexDto});"/>
                                            <input <c:out value="${optionChampInterdit}"/> type="text" name="dto[<c:out value="${indexDto}"/>].valeurSaisiForm" onfocus="change_classe_byId(this,'on');"
                                            onclick="SetSelectedControl(this,'<%= nomDuChamp %>');" style="<%=style%>" maxlength="<%=max%>" 
                                            onblur="<c:out value="${zrs}"/>;change_classe_byId(this,'off');" onchange="<c:out value="${prop}"/>" onkeyup="<c:out value="${prop}"/>" class="<c:out value="${styleClass}"/>"  value="<c:out value="${dto.valeurSaisiForm}"/>" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
                                            <input <c:out value="${optionChampInterdit}"/> type="text" id="<c:out value="${dto.nomChamp}"/>" name="dto[<c:out value="${indexDto}"/>].valeurSaisiForm" onfocus="change_classe_byId(this,'on');"
                                            onclick="SetSelectedControl(this,'<%= nomDuChamp %>');" style="<%=style%>" maxlength="<%=max%>" 
                                            onblur="<c:out value="${zrs}"/>;change_classe_byId(this,'off');"   class="<c:out value="${styleClass}"/>"  value="<c:out value="${dto.valeurSaisiForm}"/>" /> 
                                                    
                                            
    </c:otherwise>
                                    
</c:choose>
```

Functions :

```
function calculer(obj, max,field, indexTmp){
            var nameTmp = "tmpValue["+indexTmp+"]";
            if(obj!=null && ((obj.value.length== max) || (obj.value.length== 0)) && this.document.Bean.elements[nameTmp]!=null &&
                   this.document.Bean.elements[nameTmp].value!=obj.value){
                this.document.Bean.elements[nameTmp].value = obj.value;
            setTemplate(field);
            }

        }
    
    function zeros(obj, max, field,indexTmp)
    {
        alert("Inside Zeros - onBlur Called----Current Value is "+obj.value);
                
    
        var nameTmp = "tmpValue["+indexTmp+"]";
        
        if (field.substring(0,8) == "PDPMODEL")     
        {
            alert("Field is PDPMODEL");
            if(obj!=null && obj.value.length < max && obj.value.length != 0 && this.document.Bean.elements[nameTmp]!=null)
            {
            
                alert("Zeros Prefix Needed");
                var prfx="";
                for(var cnt= obj.value.length; cnt < max ; cnt++)
                {
                    prfx=prfx+"0";
                }
                
                obj.value = prfx + obj.value;
                alert("New value is "+obj.value);
                
                this.document.Bean.elements[nameTmp].value = obj.value;
                setTemplate(field);
        
                
            }
            change_classe_byId(obj,'off');
            
        }
        
        change_classe_byId(obj,'off');
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify:
The application server (jboss/weblogic whatsoever) just produces your html page that **gets rendered** inside your browser.
So, java script also runs inside your browser, its totally client side.

Having said that, I would suggest you to compare the html output as a first attempt to solve this issue (just make a "view source" in your browser, you know...)
You should see different output of the page, created by JBOSS and the one created by WebLogic.

My initial guess is that something wrong with JSTL here, maybe different versions of JSTL are supported by these two application servers. 
If its so, 
probably you should modify headers of jstl, I know sometimes in JBOSS it helps.
Just take a look on JSTL example of your version in WEB.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have used the following Tag Library URIs..<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/struts/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/struts/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/struts/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/struts/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> Do I need to change <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> to <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> ?? Thanks!